# Garbage Collection and Using - Why is memory not released after `using{}` block?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, using

I've recently been some refactoring some old database access code. I have a library of hundreds of methods which look something like this

```
public int getFoo(int id)
{
    using(SqlConnection connection = ConnectionManager.GetConnection())
    {
        string sql = "SELECT TOP(1) foo FROM bar WHERE id=@id";

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
        return (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
    }
}
```

I figured it would be a sensible thing to wrap the `SqlCommand`s into a `using{}` block (like the `SqlConnection` already is) so that resources get disposed of as soon as possible. Out of intellectual curiosity I decided to make the following little console application to see how much memory would be freed up:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = ConnectionManager.GetConnection())
{
    WeakReference reference;
    string sql = "SELECT COUNT(foo) FROM bar";
    Console.WriteLine("Memory Allocated before SqlCommand: " + GC.GetTotalMemory(true));
    using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(sql,conn))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Memory Allocated after SqlCommand: " + GC.GetTotalMemory(true));
        reference = new WeakReference(comm);

        Console.WriteLine("SQL output: " + comm.ExecuteScalar());

        Console.WriteLine(
            "Memory Allocated before dispose SqlCommand: " + GC.GetTotalMemory(true));
    }
    GC.Collect();
    Console.WriteLine("Memory Allocated after SqlCommand: " + GC.GetTotalMemory(true));
    Console.WriteLine("Reference is alive: " + reference.IsAlive);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

To my surprise this is the output I got:

> Memory Allocated before SqlCommand: 236384
>
> Memory Allocated after SqlCommand: 239160
>
> SQL output: (whatever)
>
> Memory Allocated before dispose SqlCommand: 246416
>
> Memory Allocated after dispose SqlCommand: 246548 <-- It's gone up!?
>
> Reference is alive: True <-- Why is reference still alive?

At first I though maybe my `WeakReference` might be somehow keeping `command` alive, but I commented that code out and still I got a similar result.

Why is `command` not being garbage collected here, even when `GC.Collect()` has been explicitly called? If a variable is introduced in a using block when can we expect that variable to be eligible for garbage collection?

Comment: Repeat after me: *`using` has nothing to do with garbage collection*. Its purpose is to free *unmanaged* resources. Therefore, the unmanaged resources held by `comm` may have been freed, but `comm` itself is alive and well.

Comment: It's indeterminate of when memory is actually released. Especially when you call GC.Collect() in the same scope as what you are trying to release. If you really want to determine memory usage, you need to use a profiler. And also what @FrédéricHamidi said.  =)

Comment: the using statement will just simply call 'Dispose' on the object after the block ends

Comment: I know `using` isn't the same as garbage collection, but I assumed that as I can no longer reference `command` it would be eligible for garbage collection

Comment: @Slappywag Which is true *regardless of whether or not you dispose it*.

Comment: So my misunderstanding is that just because an object is eligible for garbage collection, and `GC.Collect()` is called that does not mean said object will actually be garbage collected?

Comment: Maybe it was. But the normal change in memory used is higher then the few memory resources the SqlCommand presents. It just falls under the radar. If you want to know for sure take a good specialized MemoryProfiler.

Comment: @Slappywag, that's horribly complicated. Does the object have a finalizer? In that case, it will be scheduled for finalization on a dedicated thread and won't be collected right away. Even if the finalizer thread runs immediately, a *second* collection pass is necessary for the now-finalized object to actually be collected.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Disposing of objects has *nothing* to do with garbage collection.  Garbage collection has to do with cleaning up of *managed* resources.  Disposal is there to clean up *unmanaged* resources that the GC *isn't tracking*.

Sometimes those unmanaged resources are memory allocated explicitly without going through the GC, sometimes they're locks on a file handle, a database connection, a network socket, or any number of other possibilities.  But whatever they are, they very explicitly *won't* be the memory that the GC is tracking, which is what you're measuring.

As far as accounting for the differences, your differences are simply within the noise level of the program.  Your changes aren't meaningfully affecting how much managed memory is used, and the differences you're seeing are consistent with the normal fluctuation of memory in a program that uses garbage collection.

Comment: Aside from the normal fluctuation, I'd expect memory to go up the first time a connection was disposed because the connection pool will take up some memory.

Answer (score 1):

Upon disposal of the `SqlConnection` I would expect memory use to go up slightly, if it was the first connection used in that program.

`SqlConnection.Dispose()` and `SqlConnection.Close()` will by default store the internal class used to manage the connection in a static thread-safe collection, so that the next `SqlConnection.Open()` can use that object instead of going through the process of setting up another connection to the database.

The thread-safe collection is going to take up some memory of its own, and even if it already existed, internal objects to handle the reference to the connection would lead to an internal resize upwards.

Therefore I'd expect a small increase in size here.

> If a variable is introduced in a using block when can we expect that variable to be eligible for garbage collection?

We most certainly do not!

Think about what the GC collection does.

The first thing it does is to mark all the objects that it can *not* collect.

1. If an object is held by a `static` reference, then it cannot be collected.
2. If an object is referenced by a variable on one of the live threads' stacks, then it cannot be collected.
3. If an object is referenced by a field in an object that cannot be collected, then it cannot be collected.

Now, when you did `SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(sql,conn)` at that point a word on the current thread's stack was set to point to the object that the constructor created.

That place on the stack is then used by the machine code that is produced by the jitter for every use of `comm`.

There may or may not be other copies of that pointer put on the stack as implementation matters.

After the last use of the object in your code (the hidden implicit `comm.Dispose()` that the end of the `using` block causes) then those words in the stack **can** be reused.

They might not be. They certainly won't if you compiled in Debug mode, because it confuses debugging to have variables suddenly disappear while they are still in scope.

They aren't likely to be if the rest of the method doesn't have any code that makes use of the same space on the stack, which you don't. If for example you added a `object whatever = new object()` after the end of the `using` and before the `GC.Collect()` then you'd be more likely to find that `reference.IsAlive` was false because the jitter **might** use that part of the stack's memory of the new reference to `whatever` (especially if there was some use of `whatever` after the `GC.Collect()` so that it wasn't just optimised away entirely).

`using` is to call `Dispose()`, and the very **point** of `Dispose()` is that it has nothing to do with managed memory; if it did, then we wouldn't need it because the GC handles that for us.

Objects are collected when they can be shown to be collectable; this **can** happen any time after the last use of a reference to them, but **may** not happen until after the method in which the last use of them returns, as until then the piece(s) of memory referring to them on the stack might still refer to their location.

Comment: I suppose that begs the question then: If the ending of a `using` block doesn't necessarily make the `IDisposable` object collectable then is there any point in using `using`  unless the object has significant unmanaged resources? In my first example there seems to be no point in adding `using` because a) `SqlCommand` doesn't have any significant unmanaged resources b) the method is about to return anyway. It still looks prettier though :-)

Comment: Well, it might need to clean-up based on it being used as a [Component](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It also means that implementers of `IDbCommand` have the freedom to make use of unmanaged resources, since they can depend on users calling `Dispose()` on it. Sometimes a pointless `Dispose()` is a great thing; the pointless `Dispose()` on most `IEnumerable<T>` means we have fewer buggy `IEnumerable<T>` that should do something in `Dispose()` but don't than with `IEnumerable` where implementing `IDisposable` is optional.